# Определение типа сказуемого: простое, составное именное, составное глагольное?

Tags: глаголы, тип-сказуемого

> Князь Андрей, думавший, что ему было все равно, возьмут ли или не возьмут Москву так, как взяли Смоленск, внезапно остановился в своей речи от неожиданной судороги, схватившей его за горло.

*"Возьмут или не возьмут"* — составное глагольное сказуемое?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> В части "Возьмут ли или не возьмут Москву так". Возьмут или не возьмут
>   - составное глагольное сказуемое?

Два простых глагольных: ***возьмут, не возьмут.***